# Angular Toaster - close on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

using [angular-toaster service](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster), I need to close a toaster when an event happens. My toaster-options are

```
toaster-options="{ 'animation-class': 'toast-bottom-left','tap-to-dismiss':false, 'close-button': true}"
```

`tap-to-dismiss` is set to `false` so that you cannot just close it. I want to either :

- call `toaster.close()` from my controller
  or
- `closeHtml` of the toaster should call a function in my controller

  `closeHtml: '<a ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</a>'`

Is there any way to do such a thing? Or is there a way to close a toaster and call a function at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this answer](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/issues/225) which helped me.

```
var toastInstance = toasterService.pop('success');
toasterService.clear(toastInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
closeHtml: '<a ng-click="vm.cancel(); toaster.close()">Cancel</a>';
```

Add bellow object to options ?

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'close-button': true}"></toaster-container>
```

Comment: you can't call close() on this toaster. doesn't work

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I need something more specific thatn the basic close button. see my answer below. thanks anyways